# How to find the relation for $Q_8 ?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quaternions, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Problem taken from dummit and Foote  section $1.5$

Find a set of generators and relations for $Q_8$.

My attempt :  The quaternion group $Q_8$  is defined  by $ Q_8=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\} $

Therefore the  set of generator  are $1,i,j$ and $k$

But here  i don't know how to find  the  relation for  $Q_8$

Comment: How does the book define $Q_8$ though?

Comment: @the_fox $Q_8$  is defined  by $ Q_8=\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\} $

Comment: Where $i, j, k$ are what exactly?

Comment: A group generally has many generating sets, so it doesn't make sense to say "*the* set of generators."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $1,i,j,k$ to generate $Q_8$, but there are redundancies here. For instance, I think you know that $i^4=1$, so we don't need $1$ in the generating set (in fact, we *never* need to include the identity in a generating set). Similarly, we have $ij=k$, so we don't need $k$. Indeed, $\{i,j\}$ is a minimal generating set of $Q_8$.

As for relations, well, I gave you two above: $i^4=1$ and $ij=k$. Are these all the relations? Certainly not, since we can't deduce from these what $i^2$, or $-1\cdot j$ are.

A complete multiplication table would be a sufficient list of relations. However, like your generating set, it can be greatly reduced. In this case, the classic list of defining relations of $Q_8$ are
$$
(-1)^2=1\\
(-1)i=i(-1)=-i\\
(-1)j=j(-1)=-j\\
(-1)k=k(-1)=-k\\
i^2=-1\\
j^2=-1\\
k^2=-1\\
ij=k
$$
From these 11 multiplication table entries (as well as the 15 entries given by stating "$1$ is the identity element"), all 64 possible products may be deduced. Often, though, the first four lines here will be considered implicit (what else would $-1$ mean?), and the last one will be multiplied by $k$ on both sides to yield $ijk=-1$. This way we can write
$$
i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1
$$
and say that this defines $Q_8$.